# One-word quantifier which expresses "always, except by chance"

Tags: single-word-requests, quantifiers

I am writing a paragraph about a mathematical condition which is "always false except by chance". This chance is **very very low**, almost zero, meaning the case for the condition being true will, in practical terms, never happen. Yet, strictly speaking, **it could**.

Is there a **one-word** quantifier which can express this condition ("always, except by chance")?

For instance:

- "The condition is always false" is not appropriate, because **always** is too strong (chance still exist for condition to be true)
- "The condition is mostly false" is not appropriate, because it speaks of many cases where it holds. The case will almost never happen.

I have been looking at other quantifiers or adverbs online, but cannot come across one.

Comment: I can't think of a single word (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer) but the chance of the condition being false can be described as _vanishingly small_. This term is widely accepted, particularly in scientific and mathematical circles, and reflects the calculus concept of _tending to zero_ which is an alternative multi-word description of the situation.

Comment: barely, narrowly = almost not.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the exact sentence in which you're trying to fit this. Relatedly, can it be framed in terms of truth rather than falsity?

Comment: I support @BoldBen's comment.  In addition, I have seen this concept expressed as follows: The condition has a negligible but nonzero likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

The word I have seen used for this is ***practically***.

> "The condition is ***practically*** false"

ODO:

> **[practically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/practically)**
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** Virtually; almost.
>
> ‘the risk of default was practically zero’

Answer (score 1):

There is a mathematical term "almost always."  The accepted definition would be something like:

Almost Always

- Always except in a finite number of cases (or over a zero measure set)

An example might be:

> You can almost always divide one real number by another - dividing by zero being the exception.  Your example is almost always false.